# How to perform a "date -v -1m +%Y_%m" in a substitution variable in Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I need to get the month and year of the month prior to runtime date in my cloud build yaml file.  Try as I may, nothing I do will resolve.

I have seen posts about storing environment variables in /workspace, but haven't had any luck doing that either.

How can I perform $(date -v -1m +%Y_%m)? I can only get _$(date +%F) to resolve.

Comment: What did you try? What failed? Do you have piece of code?

Comment: As @guillaume blaquiere said if you can share your code we may help you better.

Comment: Which shell are you using? For my "bash", "date -v" gives error "date: invalid option -- 'v' ". Otherwise your approach looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [substitution variable](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values) is a good approach for your use case. As mentioned here :

> You can also apply bash parameter expansions on substitution variables

You can also look [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/use-bash-and-bindings-in-substitutions#using_bash_parameter_expansions_with_payload_bindings), using bash parameter expansions with payload bindings, once your regex pattern is resolved.

Else, [Running bash scripts](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/run-bash-scripts) is supported as well, for both inline and on disk, take your pick.